# Accessing first open element on a partially filled array

Tags: c++, arrays

With a partially filled array what does the for loop look like that enables you to continue entering data on the first open element? For example if the array is set to hold up to 50 elements but an unknown amount of them are already full what does the for loop look like that allows you to begin filling in more data on the first open element?

Comment: What's an "open element"?

Comment: please insert a snippet of code so we have something to related to

Comment: You don't use an array. You use a `std::vector<>` which, by your conditions, adds new elements via `push_back()` to the end. That also solves your which-elements-are-in-use quagmire, since they *all* are.

Comment: As in the first element that has not been filled with any information. Lets say 25 elements have been filled and you need to start filling in at element 26 (but you dont know that 25 spots have been filled).

Comment: By your last comment, the very phrasing is contradictory. "Lets say 25 elements have been filled " Ok. we *know* 25 elements have been filled. Then, ".. but you dont know that 25 spots have been filled". Um.... ?

Comment: I was choosing an arbitrary number. All I was trying to say is an unknown amount of elements have been filled and you need to access the next one. Thanks for being so helpful. I will attempt to use a vector instead.

Comment: Sounds like madness circling in one brain (we all have that)

Comment: Ok. so can there be "holes" that are unused in your array sequence or are additions always on the end? It may just be a question-phrasing thing. If no holes can be in the sequence and all new values should go to the end, I *strongly* advise using a vector-push_back approach. If you need to fill holes that are "emptied" it gets considerably more cumbersome.

Comment: I am seeing that now. I will for sure be switching to a vector approach. It seems much simpler. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of the elements. If the array holds pointers and unassigned slots are set to null, you will search for the null. If the array is an integer array, you first need to initialize it to a special value, for example -1, then search for -1. Or, you can use a structure:

```
struct Element { Element():valid(false){}; bool valid; int val; }
```

And set valid to true for assigned elements. Now you need to search for elements that are not valid:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   if (!array[i].valid) { 
      array[i].val = val; 
      array[i].valid = true; 
      break; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Lets say you have an array, int ar[50];
- Then you decide to add 30 elements to ar by calling;
- int index = 0;
- void add(int a){
- for(int i = 0;  i < 30 && i < sizeof(ar)/sizeof(int); i++) {
- ar[i] = a;
- index++;
- }
- }
- In this function ADD there is an INDEX variable which keep track of how many elements have been added to the array. This variable will represent the size of array.
- Now when you decided to add some more elements later on, first you need to check if the index is equal to array size of 50. if it`s equal then your array is full and there is no more room for additional elements otherwise if index is less than 50 then you can add more elements to it. You can then start adding elements from index position since this represent the location of the last element in the array.
- void add(int a){
- for(int i = index; i < sizeof(ar)/sizeof(int); i++) {
- ar[i] = a;
- index++;
- }
- }
- index variable must be declared as a class variable then incremented as the elements gets added to the array.